# removeClass not working on .hide or .slideup

Tags: jquery

I am not the best with jquery and I need some help with an issue I'm having...

I have this script:

```
<script>
            jQuery('.go_menu_tier').click(function(){
                var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');

                if(jQuery('.menu-'+id).is(":visible")){ 
                    jQuery('.menu-'+id).slideUp();  
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('activemenu'); 

                }else{
                    jQuery('.menu-tier-2').hide();
                    jQuery('.menu-'+id).slideDown();
                    jQuery(this).addClass('activemenu');

                }

                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

Along with this css:

```
.go_menu_tier:after{
    content: "+";
 display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}
.activemenu:after {
    content: "-";
 display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Basically have a custom wordpress menu that has a few menu items with dropdown submenu. I have it all setup correctly except for when I click one dropdown and another dropdown slidesup it doesn't apple the style to show + instead of - symbol. If I click the main menu item to slidedown the submenu then click it again the css content switches the + and - correctly. It's only when one submenu is open and I click another top menu item the previously open top menu item does not switch back to a + instead of a - sign...

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="menu-tier-2 menu-8463"><ul><li><a href="/collections/t-shirt" target="">Tees</a></li><li><a href="/collections/shirts-tops" target="">Tops</a></li><li><a href="/collections/pants" target="">Pants</a></li><li><a href="/collections/hats" target="">Hats</a></li><li><a href="/collections/walkshorts" target="">Walkshorts</a></li><li><a href="/collections/boardshorts" target="">Boardshorts</a></li><li><a href="/collections/accessories" target="">Accessories</a></li><li><a href="/collections/jackets" target="">Jackets</a></li></ul><div style="clear: both;"></div></div><div class="menu-tier-2 menu-8477"><ul><li><a href="/rl14/about/" target="">About</a></li><li><a href="/rl14/fall-2014-look-book/" target="">Look Books</a></li><li><a href="/rl14/imalive/" target="">IM Alive</a></li><li><a href="#" target="">Instagram</a></li></ul><div style="clear: both;"></div></div><div class="menu-tier-2 menu-8481"><ul><li><a href="/rl14/contact/" target="">Contact</a></li><li><a href="/rl14/dealer-select/" target="">Dealers</a></li></ul><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>
```

Comment: When you click on a different menu, you add the `activemenu` class to that one, but you never remove it from the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `activemenu` class from the previously active menu:

```
            if(jQuery('.menu-'+id).is(":visible")){ 
                jQuery('.menu-'+id).slideUp();  
                jQuery(this).removeClass('activemenu'); 

            }else{
                jQuery('.menu-tier-2').hide();
                jQuery('.menu-'+id).slideDown();
                jQuery('.activemenu').removeClass('activemenu');
                jQuery(this).addClass('activemenu');

            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar you helped me solve a 4 hour mystery. Cheers! Works great now.